# Show that the preimage of $[0, 1]$ under a polynomial is a graph

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

My question seems to be geometrically obvious. While studying the correspondence of the Shabat polynomials and bicolored plane trees I failed to find any formal proof of the correctness of the tree construction.

Consider a complex polynomial $f \in \mathbb C[x]$ such that $f'(w) = 0 \rightarrow f(w) \in \{0, 1\}\ \forall w$ (all critical values are either $0$ or $1$).

Notice that $f(x) - c$ does not have any multiple roots $\forall c \in (0, 1)$.

Now define $S := f^{-1}([0, 1]).$

[image]

1. Prove that $S$ is a union of $\deg(f)$ continious curves $\gamma_i$ such that $f(\gamma_i) = [0, 1]$ and $f|_{\gamma_i}$ is bijective. All the papers I read assumes this being obvious but I cannot give a formal proof.
2. Prove that if $z_0 \in S\ $ is a root of $f(x) - f(z_0)$ of multiplicity $k$, then $z_0$ is an intersection of exactly $k$ curves.

That will show that $S$ is a bicolored plane graph with vertices $f^{-1}(\{0, 1\})$ and $\deg(f)$ edges.

**MY PROGRESS:**
Denote $n := \deg(f)$.

If $f(x) - c$ has a multiple root $z$ for $c \in (0, 1)$ then $f'(z) = 0$. But then $f(z) \in \{0, 1\}$ and $f(z) \neq c$.

Therefore $f(x) = c$ has exactly $n$ distinct solutions and every $c\in (0, 1)$ has exactly $n$ preimages.

Now we need to define $\gamma_i.$ We can take $z_0 = \frac{1}{2}$ and consider $f^{-1}(z_0) = \{t_1, \ldots, t_n\}.$ We should define the bijective continious functions $g_1, \ldots, g_n$ such that $f(g_i(x)) = x$ and $g_i(z_0) = t_i$. That will define the desired $\gamma_i$.

For any finite set $T$ define the function $h_{T}(x)$ that maps $x$ to the closest point of $T$. Then $g_m(x)$  for $x \in (0, z_0)$ can be defined as following:
denote

$y_0 = z_0, y_k = x$, and $y_{i+1} = y_{i} - \varepsilon, i = 0, \ldots, k - 1.$

$r_0 = t_m$ and $r_{i + 1} = h_{f^{-1}(y_{i+1})}(r_{i}), i = 0, \ldots, k-1.$

Then $g_m(x) = r_k$ with $k \rightarrow \infty$(i.e. $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$)

Now I need to prove the correctness of this definition(i.e. why the limit exists) and show that the defined $g_m$ is continious and bijective.

Comment: You said "Notice that $f(x)-c$ does not have any multiple roots when $c$ is not $1$ or $0$". I assume this means you are taking that for granted, or you know how to prove that already.  This implies that every $c \in (0,1)$ has $n=\mathrm{deg}(f)$ distinct pre-images. This should give #1.

Comment: @Nick I do not see how it gives #1. Every $c \in (0,1)$ indeed has $\deg(f)$ preimages. But how to prove that the preimage is a **continious** curve? How to define the function $g_i$ that bijectively maps $[0,1]$ to $\gamma_i$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $f$ is a branched/ramified covering (meaning a covering map away from the singular values)? Covering maps are local diffeomorphisms, so a small neighborhood of $c$ is mapped diffeomorphically to a small neighborhood of any pre-image of $c$ (and so smooth curves are taken to smooth curves). Here is another post about this fact: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396119/make-a-complex-polynomial-a-covering-map

Comment: This correspondence has a proof in Lando, Zvonkin - Graphs on Surfaces and Applications, Theorem 2.2.9 (page 82, relevant part for why it is a tree is on page 83). The more general correspondence between Belyi pairs and cellularly embedded graphs is proven in Girondo, Gonzalez-Diez - Introducation to Compact Riemann Surfaces and Dessins d'Enfants.